# What is an Unlucky Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **Unlucky Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Unlucky }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[green]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  GREEN }&\text{ JADE }\\ \hline
\text{  RAIL }&\text{ TRAIN }\\ \hline
\text{  FUR }&\text{ WOOL }\\ \hline
\text{  VEX }&\text{ ANNOY }\\ \hline
\text{  ONYX }&\text{ BLACK }\\ \hline
\text{  FLAP }&\text{ WAVE }\\ \hline
\text{  SYNC }&\text{ DATA }\\ \hline
\text{  ONE }&\text{ UNIT }\\ \hline
\text{  BALK }&\text{ RESIST }\\ \hline
\text{  ART }&\text{ NICE }\\ \hline
\text{  ENVY }&\text{ SPITE }\\ \hline 
\text{  ROOF }&\text{ FLOOR }\\ \hline 
\text{  NOWHERE* }&\text{ SILENCE }\\ \hline 
\end{array}$$
                                        *** This is an Unluckiest Word™**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Unlucky Words™,Not Unlucky Words™
GREEN,JADE
RAIL,TRAIN
FUR,WOOL
VEX,ANNOY
ONYX,BLACK
FLAP,WAVE
SYNC,DATA
ONE,UNIT
BALK,RESIST
ART,NICE
ENVY,SPITE
ROOF,FLOOR
NOWHERE,SILENCE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an Unlucky Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Unlucky Words™, some more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**
**Why are they called Unlucky and Unluckiest Words™?**

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlucky Words™ are ones which

> When [rot13](https://rot13.com/) translated, produce another word.

The below shows the words

> with the rot13 cipher applied:
>
>  TERRA, WNQR
>  ENVY,GENVA
>  SHE,JBBY
>  IRK,NAABL
>  BALK,OYNPX
>  SYNC,JNIR
>  FLAP,QNGN
>  BAR,HAVG
>  ONYX,ERFVFG
>  NEG,AVPR
>  RAIL,FCVGR
>  EBBS,SYBBE
>  ABJURER,FVYRAPR
>
>  They are called this as 13 is often considered unlucky, and the longest word of this type is abjurer.

Comment: Correct, well done! I'll accept this in a bit :)

Comment: @Supersonic Not sure if this was intentional or not but when you map each of the unlucky words to numbers using A1Z26 and then sum them, the total is 666

Comment: @Karm It wasn't intentional... :(

Comment: Just added in one line I noticed you missed (pertinent to a recent puzzle this question got linked to). Also only just noticed that the original puzzle has 13 rows to solve in its table, which is a nice extra clue that hasn't been mentioned so far... :)