# A bit of meta included

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Find these two words I holler.
> One is just a color,
> the other is the place of the crawler
> but what's interesting indeed
> is that one from the other we read
> when not to spoil fun we agreed
> within our very creed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two words are:

> **GREEN** and **TERRA**

*One is just a color,*

> **Green** is a colour.

*the other is the place of the crawler*

> **Terra** means 'earth', which is where many creepy-crawlies reside.

*but what's interesting indeed*
*is that one from the other we read*
*when not to spoil fun we agreed*
*within our very creed.*

> The interesting thing about these words is that each becomes the other when their letters are shifted 13 positions in the alphabet (e.g. G is letter 7 - 13 positions along is T, which is letter 20).
>
>  Of course, performing such a 'Caesar shift' is a common practice on this site, used when one wishes to hide spoilers in a comment. We know it as '**rot-13**'!

Comment: Boy, that was fast!! I can't even accept it!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Ha! Something just clicked straight away - I think these two words were once used in a "What is a... word" puzzle that relied on this trick, and it's something that's stayed in the back of my mind ever since!

Comment: @Stiv maybe you were thinking of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98121/18250) as I think you put in the comments of how you had nearly solved it :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ah, that too, but I just found [the one I meant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87899/what-is-an-unlucky-word)! :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh, and [another](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/what-is-a-rotten-word)! No wonder  this information came to mind so readily today...

Comment: @Stiv I guess the idea has been more commonly used than either of us thought :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Indeed :) There's even [this fun little gem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30311/60644) from 2016...