# A mysterious list of words

Tags: word-property

What property do the following words have in common: gnat, green, one, onyx, rail, roof? Can you find another word that has the same property?

Comment: [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/what-is-a-rotten-word) [more](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87899/what-is-an-unlucky-word) puzzles that have exactly the same mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is

> When rot13'ed, it is another word.

Why? Because

> GNAT ---> TANG,
>  GREEN ---> TERRA,
>  ONE ---> BAR,
>  ONYX ---> BALK,
>  RAIL ---> ENVY,
>  and the last one is ROOF ---> EBBS.

As for the extra question,

> CHAT ---> PUNG

Comment: Yep you got it! I realized that there is a similar puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98121/what-should-these-be-called